# Are there any good platform independent Task Dialog implementations for .NET?

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to use [Task Dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760540%28VS.85%29.aspx) in my .NET 4 application but I need to also support Windows XP.

I've googled and there are thousands of implementations for .NET that aren't dependent on Windows Vista or above, but most of the ones I've looked at expose only a small subset of the native Task Dialog API.

The [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) has a good .NET wrapper for the native Task Dialog API, but it requires Vista or above.

I'm looking for a good quality implementation that is roughly on par with the native Task Dialog in terms of features and look and feel.  A WPF implementation complete with animations would be great!

Can anyone recommend such a thing based on past experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper.aspx), [this](http://www.lukesw.net/articles/VDialog.aspx) and [this](http://www.wintaskdialog.com/). The first one is good enough - it shows original Vista TaskDialog when a program runs on Vista or higher OS, and it shows WPF TaskDialog-like window when it's invoked on WinXP. Note that you can't get original TaskDialog on WinXP because it uses Vista+ features.

Answer (score -4):

Task Dialog is only available on Windows Vista and above, and it has nothing to to with .NET.

On your own link of [Task Dialogs API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760540%28VS.85%29.aspx), it's clearly mentioned in the MSDN Library:

> **Requirements**
>
> Minimum supported client  Windows Vista
> Minimum supported server Windows Server 2008
> Header  Commctrl.h (include Commctrl.h)
> Library Comctl32.lib
> DLL  Comctl32.dll version 6

Then you won't find any support API in Windows XP.

Comment: He suggest in it's question a WPF implementation replacing the native one for XP so I guess that he already know perfectly well what you are saying.